# How to work with the optimized resources downloaded from Google PageSpeed Insight?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, minify, pagespeed

I am working with Wordpress and using child themes. I run Google PageSpeed Insight and downloaded the optimized files (images, CSS, JS) from Google PageSpeed Insight.

I am not sure where to put the files I downloaded.

1. JS, CSS – I want to continue working with the JS and CSS which are not minified. I want the minified files to be created each time I am updating my JS/CSS files. Is that possible?
2. There are optimized files belong to the parent theme. However, I don't want to change files in my parent theme. Is there a good way to handle this issue?
3. I tried to optimize images using WordPress plugin. After optimization Google still showing  that these images should be optimized. Optimized images which I downloaded from Google PageSpeed Insight are too small to display in desktop. I don't understand how should I handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a build task runner to automate your development process. Using web performance plugins such as [the ones listed here](http://yeoman.io/blog/performance-optimization.html) would allow you to develop and automate your CSS/JS minification, image optimization, etc.

A great tool to use is [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) which allows you to work with your existing Wordpress development workflow. This means that you only need to run the build tasks once you have finished developing. There are some great tutorials that show you how to use [Grunt with Wordpress development](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-grunt-with-wordpress-development--cms-21743) and [Grunt](http://mattbanks.me/grunt-wordpress-development-deployments/) too.